# Expression to build dash pattern?

Tags: qgis, line

How can I use the expression builder to build a dash pattern for a line feature ?

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Answer (score 3):

The accepted values are displayed in the "Data defined override: Description", on top of the expression menu, in the section "expected input":

```
string [no|solid|dash|dot|dash dot|dash dot dot]
```

This means you can create an expression resulting in one of the following strings: 'no','solid', 'dash', 'dot', etc. For example, something like `if($id%2=0,'solid','dash')`

Answer (score 1):

This answer is about, how you can choose between different patterns for a line feature,
but I was looking for an **expression to choose the length of the dash and the space of a dash pattern of a line feature.**

After a long searching, I got help in this artikel :
https://tutel.me/c/gis/questions/212951/qgis+expression+builder+returning+pair+of+values+eg+coord

An example of how I now use the expression builder to draw a dashed line:
Simple line.
Pen width: 1.4*sqrt(8000/@map_scale).
Cap style: Flat.
Use custom dash pattern:
format('%1;%1;0;0', 5*sqrt(8000/@map_scale))

Comment: The first answer answers the question you asked. Perhaps you could edit your original question, explaining more about what you need to do, and also edit your answer to explain why this solution works better?